# Application Insights not logging performance counter data

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I have a console application which uses Application Insights to log telemetry data. It is able to log events. But the performance counters are not being logged.

```
var perfCollectorModule = new PerformanceCollectorModule();
perfCollectorModule.Counters.Add(new PerformanceCounterCollectionRequest(
  @"\Sales(electronics)\# Items Sold", "Items sold"));
perfCollectorModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);
```

Comment: where did you write this code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the user the application is running under is a member of the "Performance Monitor Users" group?